Disable Django admin buttons after click
Is there any easy way in Django change forms to disable buttons after submit. I want to prevent users from submitting the form twice at the same instant!

tk.Button['state'] = "disabled"

Depends on what you mean easy.
AFAIK, no Django-native solution exists for this. Preventing double-clicks is a task that falls on the client-side of things, while Django is a server framework.
(Preventing the processing of double submissions, idempotency, is a different case, and is doable although Django doesn't provide tools specifically aimed at this.)
But you can implement double-click prevention using Javascript, and the change is quite small, although it would require you to modify the HTML template the form is being rendered in.
Here is a rudimentary script that should accomplish this (for all forms, regardless of name/id, on the loaded page):
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        const forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');

        forms.forEach(form => {
            form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
                const btns = form.querySelectorAll('button[type="submit"], input[type="submit"]');

                btns.forEach(btn => {
                    btn.disabled = true;
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>

Simply add it to your template and that should be it.

Just use regular Javascript
<form method="post" action="{% url 'your_view_name' %}" onsubmit="disableSubmitButton()">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" id="submit-button">Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
    const disableSubmitButton = () => {
        const button = document.getElementById('submit-button');
        button.disabled = true;
    };
</script>

for multiple submit buttons
<button type="submit">Submit 1</button>
<button type="submit">Submit 2</button>
<script>
    const disableSubmitButton = (event) => {
        event.target.disabled = true;
</script>


There are a few things to keep in mind here. The concept you are referring to is called Idempotent. You have not shared which frontend ecosystem you are using so I am assuming basic javascript.
First, as others suggested you can simply disable the submit button right after someone clicks it. This works but unfortunately will not let the user submit again. To do so, they will need to refresh the page.
There are a few better things you can do.

You can keep track of any changes to any items in the form. Given you want to make it as simple as possible you can add something like the following in your base.html. As that will propagate this functionality everywhere in your application and you wont need to copy paste the functions everywhere



<script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            // Select all forms on the page
            const forms = document.querySelectorAll("form");

            forms.forEach((form) => {
                // Find the submit button in the form and disable it initially
                const submitButton = form.querySelector("button[type='submit']");
                if (submitButton) {
                    submitButton.disabled = true;

                    // Function to enable the submit button
                    const enableButton = () => {
                        submitButton.disabled = false;
                    };

                    // Add event listeners to all input, select, and textarea fields
                    form.querySelectorAll("input, select, textarea").forEach(field => {
                        field.addEventListener("input", enableButton);
                        field.addEventListener("change", enableButton);
                    });

                    // Disable the submit button after form submission
                    form.addEventListener("submit", () => {
                        submitButton.disabled = true;
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>




you can also re-enable the submit button after a few seconds (or whatever time you see fit as per your requirements) The benefit here is that users can resubmit the same form again if they like. Just replace the above enableButton function with the following.



const delayInMs = 3000;
let enableButtonTimer;
const enableButtonAfterDelay = () => {
    clearTimeout(enableButtonTimer); // Clear any previous timer
    enableButtonTimer = setTimeout(() => {
        submitButton.disabled = false;
    }, delayInMs);
};



